# Доступ к локальному серверу через WIFI по хосту а не по IP

Tags: laravel, apache2, wifi

conf apache

    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName laravel.local
    ServerAlias www.laravel.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel.local/public
    DirectoryIndex index.php

hosts
192.168.0.101   laravel.local

на данный момент по IP могу смотреть результат через телефон но есть необходимость доступа по хосту laravel.local
В интернете ни чего путного не нашел подскажите плиз!!!

Comment: Пропишите нужный хост и адрес в `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: hosts 192.168.0.101 laravel.local так а это что?